# jQuery use link to change database

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me out with this question:
How can I use an link for example: ?active=yes to make changes to my database? I would like use jEditble for since I'm using that for my other stuff as well.

I have no idea how to search for it so I can't find any examples.

Comment: Maybe you should ask what framework/language to start  playing with?

Comment: @gor, I'm using php and jQuery/jEditble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a server-side application to do that - you can't do it only with jQuery. You will also probably need jQuery AJAX call - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm really stuck, do you know where I can find an example script?

Comment: @Muiter: do you need an example of the server side part or of the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1):

You should use some server side web technology. PHP, ASP.Net, or Ruby on Rail for example. If it implements MVC pattern, then you could bind you link with action on server side, than could alter your database.